# Member variable null on function return

Tags: java, android, null

**Possible duplicate, but doesn't apply to my example:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454743/member-variable-is-null-after-function-return)

I have two member variables mSelectedOrderItem and mSelectedOrderItemId, both of which are un-initialised and therefore null. (Still doesn't work if I assign them null in onCreate).  There's also an ArrayList mOrderList.

In my list view, if you select an item, these variables are assigned values corresponding to the item.

I then want to use those assigned values in another method onClick, but the onClick always sees mSelectedOrderItem as null, regardless of whether it was initialised in onItemClick and I can't figure out why.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

public static String TAG = "MenuFragment";
public static final String TITLE= "Menu";
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private ListView mOrderListView;
private ArrayList<OrderItem> mOrderList;
private ArrayAdapter<OrderItem> mOrderListAdapter;
private OrderItem mSelectedOrderItem;
private Integer mSelectedOrderItemId;

/**
 * Returns a new instance of MenuFragment for managing fragments
 * 
 * @return a new instance of MenuFragment
 */
static MenuFragment newInstance() {
    return new MenuFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, container, false);

    // Set up the inner food/drink tabs
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.menu_items_fragment_container);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("food").setIndicator(FoodItemsFragment.TITLE), FoodItemsFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("drinks").setIndicator(DrinkItemsFragment.TITLE), DrinkItemsFragment.class, null);

    // Set up the list view
    mOrderListView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ordered_items);
    mOrderList = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
    mOrderList.add(new OrderItem("First item"));
    mOrderList.add(new OrderItem("Second item"));
    mOrderList.add(new OrderItem("Third item"));
    mOrderList.add(new OrderItem("Fourth item"));

    // Set the array adapter to the list view to display the contents of the standing order list
    mOrderListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<OrderItem>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mOrderList);
    mOrderListView.setAdapter(mOrderListAdapter);

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up the List View so that, when clicked, its details are shown in the details section
    // Set what happens when an item in the view is clicked
    mOrderListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Identify the element of the order list
            // Since the list positions and the array positions are the same
            // i.e. first position in the list corresponds to mOrderList.get(0)
            // use that knowledge
            mSelectedOrderItem = mOrderList.get(position);
            mSelectedOrderItemId = position;

            // Set the text of the details section
            // Would it be worth storing these as member variables since they're likely to be accessed
            // a lot?
            ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.order_name)).setText(mSelectedOrderItem.getItemName());
            ((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.order_note)).setText(mSelectedOrderItem.getItemNote());

        }
    });

    // Set what happens when the delete button is pressed
    ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.delete_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // If there's no item currently selected, do nothing
            if (mSelectedOrderItem == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mSelectedOrderItem == null");
                return;
            }

            mOrderList.remove(mSelectedOrderItem);
            mOrderListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    });

}
}
```

Any ideas?

Cheers.

**Edit:** added the entire class code.

Comment: is R.id.order_name part of the layout you return in OnViewCreated?

Comment: I think the problem lies elsewhere.  The field is not null on leaving  onItemClick or else you would have got NPE there.  And the first part of your onCick is a null check.

Comment: Aye, it's completely fine within onItemClicked, it's just always null in onClick.  I can't figure out why.  This is a Fragment within an Activity and I assumed that had something to do with the problem, but I'm not sure what, if anything.

Comment: I think that mOrderList.get(position) return null. So mSelectedOrderItem is assigned, but is assigned to null. Is mSelectedOrderItemId assigned in your onClickListener ?

Comment: @Zoubiock mOrderList is an ArrayList of a placeholder class that's just used to return a String.  I've also tested mOrderList.get(position) within both the onItemClick method and onClick method (using a constant integer as the index) and it works fine.

Comment: Strange! I think I'll need a bigger portion of your code could you add some ?

Comment: @Zoubiock I've added the meat of this class (which is a Fragment).  Hope it helps.

Comment: but where is the declaration of your variables as mSelectedOrderItem ?

Comment: @Zoubiock They're at the top of the class as member variables.

private OrderItem mSelectedOrderItem;
private Integer mSelectedOrderItemId; etc.

Comment: @Zoubiock I've now added the entire class code

Comment: Really strange, this should work.

Comment: Hence my extreme confusion.  I'm still at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem, but not necessarily the answer to the question.

I moved the entire code body into my onCreateView method instead of the segment I had in the onActivityCreated method because it occurred to me that it was still dealing with creating the interface, so that's where it logically belonged and, lo and behold, it suddenly works.

Does anybody have any idea specifically why this worked?

Answer (score 0):

Just add Log.i("Fragment","mSelectedOrderItemId = " + mSelectedOrderItemId); in your

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

And if it will be called from this method with correct value find solution in other place.

Comment: It gave the correct result, but I'm not entirely sure where else to look.  I've had a look in the Activity that manages this Fragment but I'm not sure how that could affect the variable in any way.  Any ideas?  Could the fact that this is a Fragment be messing it up in some way?